# Wordpress Rest API and AngularJS ui-sref and custom HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress, angular-ui-router

I am setting up an AngularJS app to pull some of its content from a Wordpress back-end using the wp-rest api v2.

It's working well, but certain HTML attributes are being stripped out notably if my post has HTML entered like this

`I have a <a ui-sref="trays">link</a>`

The resulting page in my angular app does not have the ui-sref, and is only

`<p>I have a <a>link</a></p>`

I have also tried

`I have a <a href= "" ui-sref="trays">link</a>`

but then I only get

`<p>I have a <a href="">link</a></p>`

I don't expect Wordpress to "understand" what `ui-sref` does, but how can I get the code to pass through to my app, which *does* understand what to do with such a link.

How do I get all the html from the back end to come through to Angular?

On the template, I have

`<div ng-bind-html="post.content.rendered"></div>`

in Postman, when querying the post I get back:

```
"content": {
        "rendered": "<p>hello there I am <strong>another</strong> post!</p>\n<p>I have a <a href= \"\" ui-sref=\"trays\">link</a>, too.</p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
```

### update

I have tried adding a filter to the `ng-bind-html` to trust the text:

`<div ng-bind-html="post.content.rendered | toTrusted"></div>`

which is using this filter

```
angular.module('app').filter('toTrusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
 return function (text) {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
 };
```

}]);

Which *does* pass through the ui-sref.  However, the link does not register as a link unless I also add an empty `href`, but then it just does to my default route, not "trays".

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the ui-router cannot find this route, check if trays route and all the files are included and try to access the route without link, put the route url in the browser and if it exists will be shown.

Comment: It exists, I can access it from other links in the site.  Also, I tried several other ui-srefs, same thing.  I can only use "normal" hrefs, not ui-sref (such as `<a href="/#/web/components/accordions">normal link to accordions</a>`